# How to get the id of the model I am currently viewing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So lets say I am in /post/2. Which shows me the post with the ID of 2.
Now in controller, how can I see what the current post id is that is being viewed?

My case is a bit different because I am also rendering a partial from another controller into the posts page. And if I delete one of the entries from that partial, I will also need to know the current post id that is being watched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but you can access the ID of any model by simply calling the `id` method on it.  For example if you have a model called Post and an instance of it called `@post` you would get the id by calling `@post.id`.

Comment: Also, a helpful method you can use on any object is `inspect` which will show you all of the variables (and their values) attached to an object.  For example, `@post.inspect`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the ID of a model by simply calling `id` on it. Example: `@post.id`

If you didn't fetch the model from the database yet, you can get the ID parameter from the URL by accessing `params[:id]`